# How can I bundle a Package with another custom Package in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import, frameworks

I created a custom Package `MyCustomPackage` and would like to mimic the following `UIKit` / `SwiftUI` behavior.

```swift
import SwiftUI / UIKit      // Already imports Foundation

import Foundation           //
import MyCustomPackage      // I have to manually import Foundation
```

How can I achieve my goal of already bundling `MyCustomPackage` with `Foundation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation
import MyCustomPackage

class BaseVC: UIViewController {

}
```

Then, use this BaseVc any where in the project

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: BaseVC {

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, can you explain this a bit further for me. Didn't quiet get it.